# SUM() of calculated field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, aggregate, alias

I have this query:

1)

```
select 
C.One
,C.Two
,C.Three
,C.Four

from mytable C

where C.One = 11052 and C.Three = 97734
```

This returns:

```
One  |Two | Three  | Four
11052   2   97734   4
11052   2   97734   4
11052   2   97734   4
11052   2   97734   4
11052   2   97734   4
11052   2   97734   4
11052   2   97734   4
11052   2   97734   4
11052   2   97734   4
11052   2   97734   4
11052   1   97734   4
11052   1   97734   4
11052   1   97734   4
11052   1   97734   4
11052   1   97734   4
11052   1   97734   4
11052   1   97734   4
11052   1   97734   4
11052   1   97734   4
11052   1   97734   4
11052   3   97734   4
11052   3   97734   4
11052   3   97734   4
11052   3   97734   4
11052   3   97734   4
11052   3   97734   4
11052   3   97734   4
11052   3   97734   4
11052   3   97734   4
11052   3   97734   4
11052   4   97734   4
11052   4   97734   4
11052   4   97734   4
11052   4   97734   4
11052   4   97734   4
11052   4   97734   4
11052   4   97734   4
11052   4   97734   4
11052   4   97734   4
11052   4   97734   4
11052   5   97734   4
11052   5   97734   4
11052   5   97734   4
11052   5   97734   4
11052   5   97734   4
11052   5   97734   4
11052   5   97734   4
11052   5   97734   4
11052   5   97734   4
11052   5   97734   4
```

Sorry for the long paste, you can see that every row is repeated 10 times for each "Column Two" value (10x for 1, 2, 3, 4, 5) total rows 50.

2)

If I write this:

```
select 
C.One
,C.Two
,C.Three
,C.Four
,sum(c.Four) as 'Sum'

from mytable C

where C.One = 11052 and C.Three = 97734
group by C.One, C.Two,C.Three , C.Four
```

Resulting in:

```
One  | Two | Three  | Four  |  Sum
11052   1       97734   4   40
11052   2       97734   4   40
11052   3       97734   4   40
11052   4       97734   4   40
11052   5       97734   4   40
```

The Sum should be 20 (4+4+4+4+4) but it shows 40 as the 10x the 4 repeats in the previous query. (Shown above).

I should end up with:

```
One  | Two | Three  | Four  |  Sum
11052   1       97734   4   20
11052   2       97734   4   20
11052   3       97734   4   20
11052   4       97734   4   20
11052   5       97734   4   20
```

What should I do to fix this to get 20 and not 40? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a subquery:

```
select a.One,a.Two,a.Three,a.Four,sum(a.Four) as 'Sum'
from (select C.One,C.Two,C.Three,C.Four
  from mytable C
  where C.One = 11052 and C.Three = 97734
  group by C.One, C.Two,C.Three , C.Four) a
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using SQL Server 2008 and up, if not please comment.
You're trying to get 5 unique rows from `myTable`; we call this `tempResult`.
Then for all the unique rows you want to append a column.
This column is the sum of column `Four` from `tempResult`.
It will have the **same value** for every row.

```
select
  One, 
  Two, 
  Three, 
  Four, 
  sum(Four) over (order by One,Two,Three,Four asc) as SumAll
from
(
  select distinct
    C.One,
    C.Two,
    C.Three,
    C.Four,
  from mytable C  
  where 
    C.One = 11052 and 
    C.Three = 97734 
) g
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
 select 
      DISTINCT C.Two
      ,C.One
      ,C.Three
      ,C.Four
      ,sum(c.Four) as 'Sum'

 from mytable C
 where C.One = 11052 and C.Three = 97734
 group by  C.Two,C.One,C.Three,C.Four
```

Comment: Hi!, t's the same output with or without distinct